# How do you eat this type of Gingko nut?

Tags: nuts

I've looked online but found no clear explanation... I had bought these Gingko nuts because I'm curious to try new flavors, but could never find how to eat them
An article online said that the outside shell could be poisonous, so I ended up getting rid of them.

I'm still wondering how these are cooked, when sold as seen on the picture (dry, white outer shell).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can roast them, or shell them and then put them into soups/congees.

This article seems to have pretty clear instructions:
http://www.thekitchn.com/ingredient-spotlight-ginkgo-nu-105591

Comment: Thanks! Even with instructions they still sound very dangerous! I tried the roasting method, but they started exploding in a very violent, noisy and scary way! Do you think the link means you to boil them *then* roast them?